# Share a generic controller across views in sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I want the following setup in my `routes.js` file

```
  '/first': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'first'
  },
  '/another': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'another'
  },
  '/last': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'last'
  },
```

So there are a set of generic pages that can all share the same controller - there's no need for these to all have a unique controller as they will do the same thing, just load a different view and load different data from the model dependant on the page requested.

I need therefore to pass a variable like `'page'` from the route provider to `PageController` that I can then act on in `PageController.viewPage`. (I realise the `'page'` variable in the above routes file is not valid, it's just to show what I'm trying to achieve.)

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a parameter through on the route:

```
 '/first/:page': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'first'
  },
  '/another/:page': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'another'
  },
  '/last/:page': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
    page: 'last'
  },
```

In your controller:

```
 var page = req.param('page');

 res.view('index/' + page, { // Where page is the page parameter and name of your page.
    stuff: stuff
 });
```

Now you can call your endpoint pages like this:

*/first/page1*

*/another/page2*

*/last/page3*

**EDIT**

You could also store your pages in the database along with a slug name and do something like this:

`'/:slug': {
    controller: 'PageController',
    action: 'viewPage',
},`

Then use `req.param('slug');` to query your page data from the database to load the correct data for the view.

If its multi layered routes you can use

`/*` and then `req.route` will contain your lookup.

Comment: That's not really what I'm trying to achieve, I don't want the paths to be different to how they are specified above, and some may be multiple directories deep which would break this parametrised approach. I just want to specify a variable for each unique path.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking to do something like `/:slug` and then you can use `req.param('slug')` to lookup a database entry of pages in your database?

Comment: this doesn't work because of the multiple "directory" structure of some paths. i don't really want to be having to hard specify multiple layers in the path like /:slug1/:slug2/:slug3 as that'd be horrible. i can actually just do a /* route and then inspect req.route in the controller to get the slug. thanks for pointing me in the right direction, this was actually far simpler than i thought!

Comment: Good stuff, I'm glad you found what you were looking for. I'll update the answer for others in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74842/discussion-between-richard-macarthy-and-artparks).